# Gearvr start GVRActivity from GVRScene

Tags: android, gear-vr

I have a 360 video player like https://github.com/gearvrf/GearVRf-Demos/tree/master/gvr-360video.

I want to instantiate this video player from a GVRScene, is it possible?

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Can be done via calling an Intent. But it is not encouraged. You should convert the 360video code to another GVRScene. In case you still want to try it out, you can pass along the activity to the GVRScene and from there fire an intent. Hope that helps.